# Inspect Firefox WebExtensions storage.local

Tags: javascript, bash, local-storage, firefox-addon-webextensions

WebExtensions can store data locally in their [storage.local](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage/local).  [Apparently](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage/StorageArea/set#Parameters) it is a key-value store and the values can be primitive types (such as numbers, booleans, and strings) or Array types.

I want to inspect what a particular WebExtension (not made by me) is storing in this area.

How can this be done?

Bonus for methods that can be automated, allowing me to extract the data from a `bash` script. But GUI solutions are very acceptable too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the data from Bash you could try to read it from the storage.js file of the extension. You should find it in your home directory (Linux). For me it was under: `~/.mozilla/firefox/{profile}/browser-extension-data/{extension}/storage.js`. On Windows it would be somewhere in appdata. On OS X I don't know.

The `storage.js` file is a json file.

I wouldn't rely on that working in the future. Firefox might switch to storing the data in an encrypted format at some point. Also don't rely on the data being up to date. Firefox might not sync the storage with the file on disk immediately.

Answer (score 6):

In Firefox

- enter `about:debugging` into the navigation bar and hit enter
- check `Enable add-on debugging` at the very top of that page
- below that you can see a list of all installed extensions. Find the one you want to inspect and click its `debug` link.
- An `Incoming Connection` prompt will show. Click `OK` to allow it.
- In the new pop up switch to the `Console` tab
- Here you can execute code in the context of the extension
- Paste the following code to get the `storage.local` content:

  ```
  chrome.storage.local.get(null, function(items) {
      console.log(items);
  });
  ```

Edit:

If you want to download the object you could stringify it, create a blob from it and then create a data URL from the blob and open it in a new tab or download it. Like this:

```
chrome.storage.local.get(null, function(items) {
    var blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(items, null,'  ')], {type: "text/plain"});
    var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    chrome.tabs.create({ url: url }); // requires that the extension has the "tabs" permission
    //chrome.downloads.download({ url: url }); // requires that the extension has the "downloads" permission
});
```

The target extension needs to have the "tabs" permission to open a tab or the "downloads" permission to start a download. 
You could also look for other ways of accessing the data. For instance through a "browserAction"/"pageAction"-popup or by sending an ajax call to an external server submitting the data in the post body...

Comment: Very cool! I am able to see the content of the object. It is perfect to get an understanding of the structure of the data of an extension. Unfortunately, huge JSON strings seem to be cut at a bit more than a thousand characters, in the console panel as well as in the object view panel at the right. Would you happen to know how to dump the full object to a file, ideally from the OS command line? Thanks a lot!

Comment: You could try to create a blob from the object and create a data url from it. Then you could simply open that url by calling `chrome.tabs.create`. I'll add an example.

Comment: And to comment on the bash automation, I don't think that browsers provide such interfaces anymore these days. It's a security issue and people have abused such interfaces in the past e.g. to install annoying toolbars into the browsers. I think all modern browsers have removed the ability to do things like that. You could of course try to read the data out of the RAM directly, but bash would not be a good tool for that.

Comment: I guess the data is stored by Firefox somewhere on the disk, though? I have managed to find where Chrome puts it, now trying for Firefox.

Comment: Interesting. I wouldn't rely on that working in the future, but for now that could do the job. Check your profile folder. `~/.mozilla/firefox/xxxxxxxx/browser-extension-data/xxxxx/storage.js` Also, I wouldn't expect the data to always be up2date. Firefox might only sync the data with the file once every few seconds or something like that.

Comment: wow not sure how I managed to miss that! Would you mind creating a separate answer for this, as both solutions are equally valid? Thanks! :-)